# SerializedName is an unresolved reference throughout Android project, gets resolve when building

Tags: android, gradle, gson, retrofit2

Everywhere in my project I see that the annotation @SerializedName is unresolved, even though I import it:

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName
```

I also have all the necessary build.gradle dependencies:

```
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0"
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.6.2"
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0"

implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
```

I've synced project files and rebuilt multiple times, but the annotation keeps getting highlighted in red by Android Studio.

The oddest part is that everything compiles, builds and works perfectly, but having all the red elements makes working on the project difficult, what could I be missing?

Comment: have you done invalidate caches and restart yet ?

Comment: @a_local_nobody I've tried this and also a clean and build + resync gradle multiple times.

Comment: facing same issue.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Just upgrade to

> implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.8'

You can find the latest version on [Github releases](https://github.com/google/gson/releases)

Comment: sadly the update also didn't work for me. SerializedName is able to resolve, but some members are removed by proguard even though it had @SerializedName attribute. I had to use my own interface to keep the class members

Comment: you are a livesaver

Comment: lastest Version is --- implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'

Answer (score 1):

retrofit and gson should have same same version to work well
inorder to work well in build.gradle(:app)

`implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.1'`
`implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.9.1'`
`implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.1'`